# How to create node project that accepts plugins

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a react project, let's call it my-app. I want other people to be able to create plugins for my-app. I have a typescript interface, and the plugin should export a class that implements it. What I don't know is how to write dependencies between the projects.

It seems that the plugin project should have dependency on my-app because it needs to import the interface. But my-app should have a dependency on the plugin so it can call the implementing class. This is bad, since it requires manually importing the class from plugin and calling the constructor of the plugin's class in my-app's code. Also it's a cyclical dependency.

What is the correct way to write dependencies in package.json to implement this plugin architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Your description of what you're trying to do is quite high level. Regarding the cyclical dependency, this one's easy to fix. Simply publish your interface in a separate project (that has no dependencies) and reference it in both your app as well as in your plugins. See more about this below.

Regarding how to instantiate your plugin, just keep in mind that one way or another, your app will have to call the constructor (or a factory method) to instantiate the plugin object. Nothing wrong with this.

Here's an example: Look at the `ExpressJS` library. and the `cors` plugin. The way you compose them in an app is something like this:

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors";

const app = express(); // here's your express app
app.use(cors()); // here you have instantiated the cors plugin and given it to your express app to use.
```

---

#### A word about TypeScript interfaces

Keep in mind that TypeScript provides **Structural Typing** as opposed to **Nominal Typing** that you might be familiar with from statically typed languages such as Java and C#. TypeScript's structural typing gives you the flexibility to enforce "type safety" between two modules without having to reference a common interface definition.

This is a long way to say that you could do entirely without a shared interface definition between your app and your plugin. As long as your plugin returns an object that matches the interface structure that your app expects (or returns an object that TypeScript can "infer" to match the interface that your app expects), that is sufficient. No need to "inherit from" a base class or "implement" an interface as you would in Java or C#. Read more about TypeScript's type checking:

- Type Compatibility: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html
- Type Inference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html

Comment: My interface has many methods and as such having an actual interface to implement makes writing the plugin a lot easier.

Comment: Great; yes in that case, create your interface definition. You'll have a few different way to reference it. You can publish it as an npm package and then `npm install` it on both your app and your plugin. Or you can take local dependency by using the mono-repo pattern and TypeScript's `composite` feature; or simply copy your interface .ts file into both projects (you'll have to manually update all copies if you make a change somewhere).